# Accessing stack objects outside a function

Tags: c++, stl, heap-memory, stack-memory

If I have a function that creates a `STL` object on the stack and adds them to the stack. For example say I make `std::pair` on the stack and add them to a `std::queue` that is made on the heap. Now if I pass the queue outside the function, can a different function that takes the queue as a parameter access the `std::pair` objects.

Comment: Copying something usually doesn't affect the something.

Comment: It will be so much easier if you would post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on a few factors you don't mention.

The first thing to check is whether you're copying the object into the queue, or copying a pointer to the object into the queue. Here's examples of each.

```
std::queue<A> copyQueue;
std::queue<A*> pointerQueue;

void addCopy(A a) {
  copyQueue.add(a);
}

void addPointer(A a) {
  pointerQueue.add(&a);
}
```

If it's storing copies of the objects, then anything with access to the queue can access that object without issue. If it's storing pointers, it depends on whether that stackframe has been reclaimed. If the stackframe is untouched, accessing that memory will be fine. Otherwise, the value will be garbage.

Legal example:
Function `A` adds a pointer to a stack allocated object to `std::queue Q`, and then passes `Q` to function `B`. Since function `A` has not yet returned, function `B` can access the object in `Q` without issue.

Garbage example:
Function `A` adds a pointer to a stack allocated object to `std::queue Q`, and then returns `Q` to its calling function `B`. Since function `A` has returned, function `B` will receive garbage if it tries to access the object in `Q`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case, since this answer is exactly the opposite of the previous two.

Comment: The other two are talking about value types (copies). I'll add in a brief snippet to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you `push` an object (`std::pair` in your case) in a `std::queue` it is copied from local scope into the `queue`. Therefore when the local object goes out of scope and is deleted, its copy in the `queue` is still valid until the queue itself gets deleted.

As a side note prefer `emplace` over `push` as it will construct the `std::pair` in place in the `queue` instead of copying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because when you "add" the object from the stack to object from the heap you will do a copy of the information that resides on stack to the "heap".